# Generic method to convert to DTO: how do I know the type of the calling object?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

I want to create an anonymous method that uses AutoMapper to quickly convert any entity to one of its already mapped DTOs. Here's my code:

```
public static class Maps
{
    public static IMapper Mapper;
    public static void Init()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap<Customer, DTO.Customer>());
        Mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }

    public static Dto ToDto<Entity, Dto>(this Entity entity)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Dto>(entity);
    }
}
```

This works, and I can use it like this in my service layer:

```
public DTO.Customer GetById(int Id)
{
    return dbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id).ToDto<Customer, DTO.Customer>();
}
```

However, since my `FirstOrDefault()` result is of `Customer` type, it seems redundant to have to put it in the call. How do I change the `ToDto()` method so that I don't need to include the `Entity` and simply call it using `ToDto<DTO.Customer>()`?

Comment: The AutoMapper extension method `ProjectTo` already does this for you.

Comment: @GertArnold That's interesting, but I'd still like to know how to solve my problem.

Comment: You can check the  source code of Automapper on github. It uses a non-generic `IQueryable` to have only one type parameter in the method. I remember some first versions of this extension used an intermediate type returned by another method, sth like `query.Project().To<DTO>()`. Anyway, you should use the Automapper's `ProjectTo()`, as it will add the projection to the query expression and execute it on the db.